# How to Generate an Array of Random Number Sets in PHP?

Tags: php, random

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create an array of sets of randomly selected numbers from a range. So, for instance I have a range of numbers from which to select: 1-100. I want to generate X number of sets of 5 of those numbers WITHOUT DUPLICATES. So, I want to generate something like:

```
[3, 24, 32, 49, 68]

[2, 18, 43, 76, 98]

[10, 12, 23, 45, 67]

[5, 56, 64, 72, 90]

...
```

I know how to generate random numbers from a range once, I just am stuck on doing it X number of times without the possibility of duplicate sets.

Comment: If you remove so-called "duplicate sets" then it would not be truly random. To get what you want you would generate a set from the larger set, remove the numbers from the smaller set, then generate the next set - rinse, lather, repeat.

Comment: Just gonna answer this here, because I honestly don't think this question should have been closed: `$a = range(1, 100); shuffle($a); $sets = array_chunk($a, 5); var_dump($sets);` Cheers!

Comment: @Sherif agreed, this shouldn't have been closed as a duplicate. Voted to reopen. And also great solution, post as an answer if it get's reopened

Comment: Reopened the question - I agree it's not a duplicate of what it was closed for.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is simply to generate the desired range `$arr = range(1, 100)`, then shuffle it to randomize `shuffle($arr)` then chunk it to get sets of 5 `$sets = array_chunk($arr, 5)`.

So the final answer:

```
$arr = range(1, 100); // gives us an array of 100 integers 1-100
shuffle($arr); // randomly orders those integers
$sets = array_chunk($arr, 5); // creats an array of arrays of sets of 5 integers

foreach ($sets as $set) {
    echo implode(',', $set), "\n";
}
```

Gives you something like...

```
14,24,60,95,86
47,54,10,77,3
11,22,88,80,39
72,46,81,78,59
63,98,52,82,8
79,34,43,13,41
67,33,75,1,2
4,57,84,73,17
32,55,35,18,70
64,85,100,93,71
25,19,26,20,76
99,89,7,87,91
37,97,68,27,5
74,48,65,61,58
45,31,9,30,21
16,56,50,96,90
92,40,6,44,23
28,94,38,83,29
36,62,51,66,15
12,69,49,42,53
```

### Alternative implementation

Another way to solve this problem, that doesn't require writing the entire array into memory at once and then resorting it randomly, would be to use a hashset that tracks all randomly generated integers to prevent duplicates. This gives us the same exact result except that we do both the random number generation and sorting in a single step instead of two. You can also even do the chunking in the same step this way.

> Keep in mind, however, that this solution is technically slower since it's in **unbounded time** (we have to keep guessing if the number already exists).

I'm going to use a generator to implement this solution since it's easier to write than an `Iterator` pattern.

```
function randomizeIntegerXRangeChunked($start, $end, $chunks = 5): Generator
{
    $inSet = []; // track the integers already in the set

    for ($i = $start, $c = 0; $i <= $end; $i++) {
        /* solution is in unbounded time */
        while (isset($inSet[($n = mt_rand($start, $end))]));

        $inSet[$n] = true;

        yield $c => $n;

        if (!($i % $chunks)) {
            $c++;
        }
    }
}


$arr = [];

foreach (randomizeIntegerXRangeChunked(1, 100, 5) as $chunk => $int) {

    $arr[$chunk][] = $int;

}

var_dump($arr);
```

The output will be similar to...

```
array(20) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(43)
    [1]=>
    int(52)
    [2]=>
    int(38)
    [3]=>
    int(73)
    [4]=>
    int(55)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(59)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
    [2]=>
    int(71)
    [3]=>
    int(47)
    [4]=>
    int(50)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(54)
    [1]=>
    int(19)
    [2]=>
    int(60)
    [3]=>
    int(40)
    [4]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(26)
    [1]=>
    int(46)
    [2]=>
    int(93)
    [3]=>
    int(80)
    [4]=>
    int(63)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(18)
    [1]=>
    int(45)
    [2]=>
    int(98)
    [3]=>
    int(1)
    [4]=>
    int(72)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(37)
    [1]=>
    int(97)
    [2]=>
    int(15)
    [3]=>
    int(68)
    [4]=>
    int(8)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(34)
    [1]=>
    int(14)
    [2]=>
    int(33)
    [3]=>
    int(24)
    [4]=>
    int(65)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(4)
    [1]=>
    int(16)
    [2]=>
    int(13)
    [3]=>
    int(41)
    [4]=>
    int(86)
  }
  [8]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(95)
    [1]=>
    int(12)
    [2]=>
    int(44)
    [3]=>
    int(66)
    [4]=>
    int(83)
  }
  [9]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(67)
    [1]=>
    int(48)
    [2]=>
    int(91)
    [3]=>
    int(27)
    [4]=>
    int(79)
  }
  [10]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(56)
    [1]=>
    int(25)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
    [3]=>
    int(64)
    [4]=>
    int(78)
  }
  [11]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(57)
    [1]=>
    int(17)
    [2]=>
    int(74)
    [3]=>
    int(42)
    [4]=>
    int(69)
  }
  [12]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(96)
    [1]=>
    int(20)
    [2]=>
    int(9)
    [3]=>
    int(28)
    [4]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [13]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(30)
    [1]=>
    int(75)
    [2]=>
    int(21)
    [3]=>
    int(6)
    [4]=>
    int(89)
  }
  [14]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(51)
    [1]=>
    int(36)
    [2]=>
    int(62)
    [3]=>
    int(58)
    [4]=>
    int(23)
  }
  [15]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(85)
    [1]=>
    int(32)
    [2]=>
    int(100)
    [3]=>
    int(61)
    [4]=>
    int(49)
  }
  [16]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(39)
    [1]=>
    int(87)
    [2]=>
    int(76)
    [3]=>
    int(70)
    [4]=>
    int(22)
  }
  [17]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(88)
    [1]=>
    int(77)
    [2]=>
    int(10)
    [3]=>
    int(99)
    [4]=>
    int(53)
  }
  [18]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(94)
    [1]=>
    int(35)
    [2]=>
    int(92)
    [3]=>
    int(90)
    [4]=>
    int(84)
  }
  [19]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(81)
    [1]=>
    int(82)
    [2]=>
    int(31)
    [3]=>
    int(29)
    [4]=>
    int(11)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this as well.

```
// Array
$NumberArray = array();
$TempArray = array(); // Used for storing randoms while we check via if statement.

// Loop 5 times.
for ($x=0; $x<=4; $x++) {

    // Random Number 1-100
    $RandomNumber = rand(1,100);

    // We can use Array Push to add to the array and check using in_array.
    array_push($TempArray, $RandomNumber);

    // Check first thing in temp array and see if its already in number array. (If not then push)
    if (!in_array(reset($TempArray), $NumberArray)) { 
        array_push($NumberArray, reset($TempArray)); // Add to NumberArray
        // Clear Temp Array
        $TempArray = array();
    } else {
        // Add to the loop
        $x--;
    }

}

print_r($NumberArray);
```

This outputs an array like such:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 32
    [1] => 26
    [2] => 59
    [3] => 96
    [4] => 34
)
```